# delete whitespaces in bash (no subprocess)

Tags: bash, whitespace, string-matching, removing-whitespace

I have a string in a variable and want to delete all whitespaces. I wish to do it with bash-only. Currently I remove only spaces, but I want to remove tabs also and in one step.

```
string="test    string 1" # first whitespace in string is tab second is space
echo ${string// /} # the whitespace between // is space; output: test   string1
echo ${string// /} # the whitespace between // is tab; output: teststring 1
```

The wide whitespace are tabs. The third `/` could be removed.

@anubhava I read those strings line by line from a file, so there are no newlines in my string. Therefore it can't do any harm to remove all whitespaces.

Comment: Two things: what in your `$string` is tab and what is space? Also, although it does not affect to this case, to see the output properly it is always good to `echo "$var"`.

Comment: @user2546460 Do you want to remove newlines also from string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of attempting to replace a *space*, use a character class that would match any *whitespace*:

```
$ string=$'test\tstring 1'
$ echo "$string"
test    string 1
$ echo "${string//[[:space:]]/}"
teststring1
```

`[:space:]` denotes `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`, i.e. it would match a space, tab character, carriage return, newline, and form feed.

As [@glennjackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) points out, you could remove the horizontal whitespace by using the character class `[:blank:]`:

```
echo "${string//[[:blank:]]/}"
```

If you want to remove only spaces and tabs, say:

```
echo "${string//[ $'\t']/}"
```

Comment: There's also `[:blank:]` which is just "horizontal" whitespace: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Character-Class-Operators.html#Character-Class-Operators

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks.  Age is showing up it's effect.  I'll update the answer to add what you've mentioned.